# JavaScript will not run from Chrome extension context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Disclaimer: I am new to JavaScript and I have never developed a Chrome extension before.

I am trying to develop a Chrome extension that runs some JavaScript when the user selects some text on a page, right-clicks, then clicks a context menu button. I have determined (based on running it from the Chrome console) that the JavaScript I've written runs as expected. Now all is left is to make an extension.

I can get the extension to load, and I can get it to appear on the page and to appear to run. However, it doesn't seem to do anything, and the console doesn't return any output. (I read that I can't run inline JavaScript with event pages, hence using `addListener`.) Have I set up the context menu incorrectly? Is there an error (or several) in my script?

> manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

> background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var context = "selection";
  var title = "My Extension";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                         "id": "context" + context});  
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(getSHA);

// Get file path of file to be staged
// Get SHA
function getSHA(){
    stagedFile = window.getSelection().toString()
    console.log(stagedFile)
    baseURL = window.location.href.slice(0, -6); 
    prNumber = baseURL.slice(-4); 
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/pulls/"+prNumber, false); 
    xhr.send(); 
    json_data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
    shaValue = (json_data.head.sha)
    console.log("SHA: "+shaValue)
    getNetlify;
};

// Get Netlify URL
function getNetlify(){
    xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr2.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/commits/"+shaValue+"/status", false); 
    xhr2.send(); 
    json_data2 = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText, function(key, value) { if (key == "target_url" && value.includes("netlify")) { netlifyURL = value; }});
    openStaging
};

// Stage file
function openStaging(){
    window.open(netlifyURL+"/"+stagedFile)
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a "content script" to your manifest.json. That is the kind of code that gets injected into the page to run. The background script didn't have access to the page at all. So, check out the documentation on content scripts. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

You need to add the following piece to your code to your `manifest.json`:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
    "css": ["mystyles.css"],
    "js": ["myscript.js"]
  }
]
```

With this code, any time the user goes to a site that "matches" the url I provided, then the extension will inject into that page `mystyles.css` and `myscript.js`. So... your pattern would be something like `http*://*/*` . That will inject the script onto any page that the user will go to.

Next, to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish, you don't need a background script. So you can remove that from your `manifest.json`.

So your `manifest.json` would look like this:

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Then put your code into the `myscript.js` file (or whatever you want to call yours), and you should see this start to run on the page.

Comment: Would you elaborate? I tried following the Content Scripts docs, but I became more lost...

Comment: Check the response now. I updated it. @celestialroad

Comment: Thanks for elaborating! However, I am not sure where a .css file comes into play? Is that a file I'm writing? A file I'm looking for on the website I'm using? If the latter, how would I determine which file to use? Thanks for your patience. @frosty

Comment: No. If you don't have any custom CSS, then you can remove the `css:['mystyles.css']` piece of that `content_scripts` section.

Comment: @celestialroad I only included the css, so that you would see how to also include a CSS file. But if you don't need it, don't include it. From your example, you would only need the `js` array in there.